# Loop array and if key value exists add 1 to structured array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, count

I have a MySQL result that looks as follows in json

```
[
   {
      industry: "Building",
      province: "Gauteng",
      status: "review"
   },
   {
      industry: "Building",
      province: "Gauteng",
      status: "sent"
   },
   {
      industry: "Air Conditioning",
      province: "Cape Town",
      status: "free"
   }
]
```

I and trying to take this result and generate an array that looks as follows

```
{
   Gauteng: {
      Building: {
         sold: 2,
         free: 0
      },
   },
   Cape Town: {
      Air Conditioning: {
          sold: 0,
          free: 1
      }
   }
}
```

Items are grouped by province and industry and the last level of the array needs to contain 2 keys "sold" & "free". Sold is classified as anything with sent or review in it and free is anything with a status of free.

My problem is I can make the array to the point of Province > industry by not sure how to check and add up all the values for sold and free.

This is my current code in using.

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT industry, province, status FROM messages WHERE MONTH(updated_at) = MONTH(CURDATE())");

$result = array();

    foreach($query as $item) {
      $result[$item->province][$item->industry] = array(
        "sold" => 12,
        "free" => 23
      );
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
```

which gives me the result above.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to write a query that returns the data in the format you want rather than doing the grouping and aggregating later in code. Is it possible to adjust your query here? It may be useful to include your current query in your question.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Thanks I included it in the code portion above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your existing MySQL query I believe this achieved what you wanted:

```
foreach($query as $item) {
        if(empty($result[$item->province][$item->industry])){
            $result[$item->province][$item->industry] = array(
                "sold" => 0,
                "free" => 0
            );
        }
        switch($item->status){
            case('free'):
                $result[$item->province][$item->industry]['free']++;
                break;
            case('sent' || 'review'):
                $result[$item->province][$item->industry]['sold']++;
                break;
        }
    }
```

If that specific province, industry combination doesn't exist yet, create an array item with sold and free set to 0.

And then depending on the item status +1 to the necessary key.

Pretty self explanatory.